# remove all characters from a string other than a specified list of indices python

Tags: python, string

I have two strings:

```
strA='EEEEEE     HHHH      HHHHHHH'
```

and string B of equal size

```
strB='AJKFKKJSNCKSJNFKSJASLOINCLAJ'
```

I want to create a third string `strC` which only has the characters in `strB` corresponding to a given character in `strA`.

For example I am interested in position of characters in `strB` corresponding to 'H' in `strA`, the output should look like:

```
strC='           SJNF      OINCLAJ'
```

with the gaps intact.

I tried this:

```
def find(s, ch):
    return [i for i, ltr in enumerate(s) if ltr == ch]
```

temp= find(strA,'H')
The output is:

```
temp= [11, 12, 13, 14, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27]
```

when I tried creating a new string, `str_new` by doing the following:

```
str_new = strB[temp]
```

I get an error

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `zip`:

```
strA='EEEEEE     HHHH      HHHHHHH' 
strB='AJKFKKJSNCKSJNFKSJASLOINCLAJ'
strC = ''.join([' ' if b != 'H' else a for a, b in zip(strB, strA)])
```

Output:

```
'           SJNF      OINCLAJ'
```

Comment: Classic **zip** use. +1. Added brackets to make it quicker.

Comment: `strD = [i for i in strC.split(' ') if i]` can be simplified as `strD = strC.split()`